# cakephp 3 show latest value with contain

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

i have a little problem with cakephp 
i have DB 
measurers => id, title, color...
usages => id, measurer_id, value...

and i want to do something like

```
$this->paginate = [
    'contain' => [
        'MeasurerTypes',
        'Usages' => function($q) {
            return $q->find('latest');
        }
    ],
    'finder' => ['my' => $this->user['id']]
];
$this->set('title',__('My measurers'));
$this->set('measurers', $this->paginate($this->Measurers));
$this->set('_serialize', ['measurers']);
```

this is only example code, is there to find only one latest variable and no all list for that?

Comment: What do you mean by "latest variable"?

Comment: i want to show latest usage to each one measurer

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

> http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/additional-methods-and-properties.html#model-getinsertid

Example:

```
$lastItem = $this->YOURMODEL->getInsertID();
```

Edit:
In CakePHP 3

> http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html

```
$result = $articles->find('all')->all();

// Get the first and/or last result.
$row = $result->first();
$row = $result->last();
```

Comment: Your edit looks more relevant than your first version of this answer - but only just. I don't think you've understood the question (it's _probably_ related to a join, find measures by "last usage" according to data in a join table)